How to directly connect a kmp desktop app with mysql
We are working on a multiplatform app, for this KMP (Kotlin Multiplatform) has been used, the app is planned to be launched in three versions, IOs, Android and Desktop, in the desktop section, it has to connect directly to MySQL without having to use an external service, this is because the desktop app will only run on the internal "server", this desktop app has to use certain sensors so a website is not viable, the question we have is:
Is it possible to connect Kmp with MySQL directly or is it necessary to create a service that allows it?

Since kotlin can use jdbc drivers and there is a jdbc driver for mysql, yes, it is possible for a kotlin app to directly connect to a mysql server. Whether it should do so, is a completely different question.

You should be able to connect using SQLDelight, though I have not tried this personally.
